# Using charcode to allow only numbers and enter key

Tags: forms, syntax, onkeypress

I have this syntax:

```
<input onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57">
```

I use it on inputs to allow only numbers.
But now i need to allow the enter key too since i can no longer use a button to submit the form(personal reasons).By now i found this:

```
  event.charCode = 13 // allows enter key
```

but i can't seem to find how to build the onkeypress syntax.Any help ? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try:

```
onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 8 && event.charCode <= 57"
```

In this way you can allow enter key,numbers..and few other characters,except for alphabetic characters.I don't see any other way.
Source: [click](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

Comment: How to allow only numbers and one decimal point values. For example allowing the user to input values like 0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5 and not 0.33,1.265,2.12

Answer (score 3):

You might try:

```
onkeypress="return (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57) || event.charCode == 13"
```

`event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57` is for numbers 0-9
`event.charCode == 13` is for enter

Answer (score 1):

If you do something like:

```
onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 8 && event.charCode <= 57"
```

and you want the user to be able to delete or backspace make sure you include:

```
onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46'
```

The keycodes to 8 and 46 are the delete and backspace. The first solution only works completely in chrome.

Comment: what should I include for dash -

Answer (score 0):

It's not a very good style to include js code into html. Also if there is more than one input you need to avoid code duplicating. 
So include this to your js file, the other code can be the same

```
$('.div-with-multiple-inputs').find('input').on('keypress', function() {
        return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, allow only numbers 0-9 and .

```
onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 46 && event.charCode <= 57"
```